# Getting NullPointerException in onpostexecute method

Tags: android

Problem is in onpostexecute method

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        contactListView = getListView();
        contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewContactListener);

        String[] from = new String[]{"name"};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.contactTextView};
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        CursorAdapter contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(AddressBook.this,          
                R.layout.contact_list_item, null, from, to);
        setListAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        new GetContactsTask().execute((Object[])null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor cursor = contactAdapter.getCursor();
        if(cursor != null)
            cursor.deactivate();
        contactAdapter.changeCursor(null);
        super.onStop();
    }

    private class GetContactsTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor>{
        DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = DatabaseConnector(AddressBook.this);

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            databaseConnector.open();

            return databaseConnector.getAllContacts();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            contactAdapter.changeCursor(result);
            databaseConnector.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Think. What could be `null`? Test it. Is it `null`? Fix it.

Comment: Judging from the contents of your code and the error your receive, I'm guessing that either `contactAdapter` or `databseConnector` are null. However, lacking any more information it is rather difficult to help you any more than that.

Comment: check the values of contactAdapter & databaseConnector

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are declaring contactAdapter on onCreate. Do you have another contactAdapter as  class member? My guess is yes, but since you are declaring one at method level (onCreate) your  class member will never be set.